# Setting up a recursive mapping with fluent for Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, fluent

How does one setup the mapping in fluent for this type?

```
public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Title { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Children { get; set; }    
    public int ParentId { get; set; }    
    public Topic Parent { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Related { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that ParentId is not required as not every topic will have a parent.

```
public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Topic Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Related { get; set; }
}
```

then the mapping would look something similar to

```
public class TopicMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Topic>
{
    public TopicMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(42);

        ToTable("Topic");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        Property(t => t.ParentId).HasColumnName("ParentId");

        // Relationships
        HasOptional(t => t.Parent)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId);
        //Topic might have a parent, where if it does, has a foreign key
        //relationship to ParentId
    }
}
```

And plugin on model binding:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TopicMap());
    //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TopicChildrenMap()); ..etc
    //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TopicRelatedMap());  ..etc
}
```

I'd also recommend getting your hands on [the EF Power Tools CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx). It's very helpful in learning and understanding how to create fluent configs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I this simply adding HasOptional(p => p.Parent) is enough for the relationship. Otherwise the WithMany causes topics to appear as children and related when they shoudln't.

Comment: Can it be done such that the children are deleted in a cascade manner? How about the parent automatically being set?

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question as well. I am wondering, though, if the "Children" and "Parent" properties names are required conventions of the language, or if their names can be changed.